# How do I retrieve innerhtml using watir webdriver

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I have the following HTML, and I need to get the text that is outside of the bold tag.  For instance 'Submitted At:' I need to get the timestamp that follows.  You will see that 'Submitted At: is surrounded by bold tags and the timestamp follows and I can not retrieve it.

```
<body>
    <h2> … </h2>
    <b> … </b>
     jenkins
    <br></br>
    <b> … </b>
    <br></br>
    <b> … </b>
    <a href=""> … </a>
    <br></br>
    <b> … </b>
    <br></br>
    <b>
        Submitted At:
    </b>
     29-Jan-2016 17:12:24
```

Things I have tried.

@browser.body.text.split("\n")

@browser.body.split("\n")

body_html = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(@browser.body.html)

body_html.xpath("//body//b").text

- returned: "User: JobName: JobConf: Job-ACLs: All users are allowedSubmitted At: Launched At: Finished At: Status: Analyse This Job"

I have tried several things such as xpath, plain old text retrieval, but I am not able to get what I need.  I have also done several searches and can't find what I need.

Comment: It seems fragile and lame, but you could chain `String::scan` to pull the timestamp.  Contrived example: `b.text.scan(/\d.*\d/)`

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the links at the bottom, and "[mcve]". We need to see your attempt to solve the problem, otherwise it looks like you're trying to get us to write code for you.

Comment: you'd probably be better off just parsing it as a huge string. upvoting just to prevent new user from losing karma. also voted to close

Answer (score 0):

To start with, html bereft of classes and ids is always going to provide a challenge. It is going to be even worse when you want to access text that is merely in the body tag.
In this specific instance, this should work:

`browser.b(index: 4)`

Comment: Thank you for responding. I did try the above before posting but it only gives me "Submitted At:" and I need the time stamp that follows which is not surrounded by tags.

Comment: Yes, that's the text that is in between the b tags, I missed that you needed the actual time stamp, which, right, makes sense. You're pretty much going to have a difficult time and be forced to deal with inelegant solutions if you're working with text that is directly in the body tag.

Answer (score 0):

1. InnerHtml is literally what it is - its inside a HTMLstart and end tag. So you are looking at InnerHtml of the outer tag actually - `<body>`.
2. The `.text` of `<Body>` tag will give you entire text. If the tags are gonna be dynamic index is not going to work. So if you know the timestamp length is gonna always be same, Get the entire text, delimit/unstring based on this string 'Submitted At:' to max timestamp length. This will be stable solution rather than a hardcoded Index value if it may change. Ie pickup substring starting from that tag to max length of timestamp.

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I have tried .text on the <body> tag but the time stamp does not return.  I did browser.text and the information I need is there though I do not feel this the most efficient way of getting that data.

Comment: @Joe, are you saying that `browser.body.text` returns something different than `browser.text`?

Comment: @joe Can you pls give me the full html?. and how did you find the <body> tag element

Comment: @JustinKo  Sorry, no.  They both bring back the same data.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML appears to have a structure of:

- a `<b>` tag that is the field description and
- a following text node that is the field value.

Watir can only return the concatenation of all an element's text nodes. As a result, it does not deal well with this structure, which needs the text nodes separated. While you could parse the concatenated String, it could be error prone depending on the possible field descriptions/values.

I would therefore suggest parsing the HTML with Nokogiri as it can return individual text nodes. This would look like:

```
html = browser.html
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
p doc.at_xpath('//b[normalize-space(text()) = "Submitted At:"]
                 /following-sibling::text()[1]').text.strip
#=> "29-Jan-2016 17:12:24"
```

Here we are using an XPath to find the `<b>` tag that contains the relevant field description, "Submitted At:". From that node, we find the text node, ie the "29-Jan-2016 17:12:24", that comes right after it.

Comment: I gave that a try and it returned:                                                       NoMethodError: undefined method `text' for nil:NilClass
from cdh5.rb:137:in `get_info'